# XAML Material Design TabControl without dragablz

Tags: xaml, material-design, tabcontrol

Hey where can I find a sample of a Material Design TabControl without dragablz? All samples are with dragablz... Like the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use **MaterialDesignTabControl** provided with [MaterialDesignExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialDesignExtensions/).

Answer (score 3):

as @fruggiero said MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit  doesn't have any styling for tabcontrol... But here you can achieve the same tabcontrol like functionality with the look you want,

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <materialDesign:ColorZone Mode="PrimaryMid">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}" x:Name="rbTab1" Margin="4" IsChecked="True" Content="TAB 1"/>
                <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}" x:Name="rbTab2" Margin="4" Content="TAB 2"/>
                <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTabRadioButton}" x:Name="rbTab3" Margin="4" Content="TAB 3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1 0 1 1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" Padding="16">
            <Grid>
                <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbTab1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is tab page 1 content" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbTab2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is tab page 2 content" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rbTab3, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="This is tab page 3 content" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you!

Comment: This was helpful. However, you may want to define a static resource for the BooleanToVisibilityConverter so some persons who are new to XAML may not be confused as to why the Grid visibility isn't working.

Comment: @Bloggrammer its already included in MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit converters, check at https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Converters

Answer (score 0):

The **MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit** actually does not provide styling for the tabcontrol.

So, you can only use the dragablz tabcontrol and configure it to your need.